# Do I need to keep Calendar app open in order to be notified about calendar events

Tags: high-sierra, calendar, ical

I think this question can be very trivial, but for some reason it seems extremely difficult to find a clear and explicit answer to this.

If I close the Calendar app (by selecting "Quit") and therefore its icon disappears from the Dock, is there still some daemon process running in the background and therefore I will still be notified about Calendar events? Or do I need to keep the app open?

For example, some apps like Microsoft Outlook must stay open in order to be notified about e-mails, therefore this is not necessarily something which is not needed to be said.

Ideally, is there any official or reliable *source* that says this? (e.g. official documentation)

Comment: Quick test, set a diary note for 20 minutes in the future with a 15 min alert, then quit Calendar.

Comment: I think it works, thanks... although it would have been nice if they explicitly said somewhere that there is a service running in the background, just to be on the safe side...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. If you set System Preference > Notifications > Calendar to Allow Notifications you should get a notification if you set the alert style to Banners or Alerts even if the app has been quit:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is there any official or reliable source that says this? (e.g.
> official documentation)

Not explictly, but one can imply it from support document called [If you don’t receive calendar alerts on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/if-you-dont-receive-calendar-alerts-on-mac-icl1025/11.0/mac/11.0). There is is list of possible causes of not receiving alerts and none of them is 'because Calendar app is not running'.